# PUT condition is giving bad request when I am giving through parameter

Tags: jmeter

Have a put condition and when I am passing the parameter in the path it is working fine but when I am giving it from the parameter section it is giving me bad request.

Working fine with 204 status code:

[image]

Not working with 400 error

[image]

I am using same header manager and everything is intact. What I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing here one important bit: you should not be comparing one JMeter request to another JMeter request, you need to take a look at the request from the real browser using "Network tab" of the [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and then replicate it in JMeter with 100% accuracy.

A faster and an easier way would be just recording your request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).

If you still want to know "what you are missing here" take a look at requests using View Results Tree listener, my expectation is that JMeter is sending "selectedState" as `Processing.Initial+Test+Passed` and looking into URL query string you have `Processing.Initial%20Test%20Passed` there. Most likely developers of the application you're trying to test are not too familiar with the [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)